# How can I cancel a `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:`?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, performselector

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [cancelling queued performSelector:afterDelay calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1806445/cancelling-queued-performselectorafterdelay-calls)

I have code to delay displaying my result by 6 seconds. However, I want to be able to abort this delay if the user continues on. I'm not sure how I can cancel the delay method call once it's started. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

This is the code I use to call the delay method and the method below.

```
[self performSelector:@selector(delay) withObject:nil afterDelay:6.0];

-(void)delay{
    [buttonScreen setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:32.0]];
    buttonScreen.text = [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:result]];
}
```

Comment: You can use an NSTimer to trigger the action.

Comment: It is a repost (I did not find the linked until I saw your post). Apologies! Used that to solve my problem (very good explanation! The one below was pretty good too :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` is in the NSObject class documentation. So the thing to do is look in the NSObject class documentation to see what else is there. If you do, you'll see this:

> `cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:` Cancels perform requests
>   previously registered with the `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:`
>   instance method.

Comment: +1 for helping explain a documentation search strategy (as well as correct answer)